# Range for raw analog import in PulseView (SigRok)?

Tags: software

Apologies in advance if I chose the wrong forum - this is mostly a software question; however, I thought it would be irrelevant to most on StackOverflow that don't do electrical engineering, so I hoped I could get an answer here. If not, please advise a more appropriate place where this question can be moved.

I'm using PulseView (sigrok) on Windows 10 installed via:

- https://sigrok.org/download/binary/pulseview/pulseview-0.4.1-64bit-static-release-installer.exe

I want to analyse multichannel raw analog (binary) data in PulseView. First problem I had, was not knowing how PulseView interprets multi-channel data - interleaved, or not (that is, channel 1 in its entirety, followed by channel 2 in its entirety).

Eventually, I've made this simple test in Python:

```python
import struct

with open('binfile', 'wb') as f:
  for ix in range(256):
    f.write(struct.pack("=B", ix))
```

Then, I imported this via Open icon in PulseView/"Import Raw analog data without header..." (remember to set the file filter to "All files", otherwise `binfile` will not be listed, as only `.raw` or `.bin` file extensions are shown by default), and used:

- Data format: U8 (8-bit unsigned int)
- Number of analog channels: 10
- Sample rate (Hz): 0

This imports, and gives this plot (after manually setting all "Vertical Resolution" to 1V/DIV, accessed when you left-click the CH1 etc labels which sit at the left of the tracks):

[image: binfile-pulseview]

As it can be seen, when the cursor is over the leftmost sample in the multitrack, the values we get are: -500 mV, -496 mV, -492 mV, -488 mV, -484 mV, -480 mV, -476 mV -- which for me, means that PulseView interpreted the data in `binfile`, to be interleaved, as in:

```
byte1|byte2|byte3|...|byte10|byt11|byt12|byt13|.....
  ==
ch1s1|ch2s1|ch3s1|...|ch10s1|ch1s2|ch2s2|ch3s2|.....
```

So that question is solved (hopefully, unless I interpreted it wrongly)

What I still don't get, is:

- Why did PulseView decide to map byte value 0x00 to -500 mV, and byte value 0xFF to 500 mV? In other words, how did it decide on this default range - is this documented anywhere, and can I change the interpreted analog range (in volts)?
- When I use Sample rate (Hz): 0, PulseView seemingly choses 10 ms as sample period by default. Why is this number chosen, and is this documented anywhere? (I expect if I enter a proper sampling rate, then I'll get the corresponding sampling period instead).

Comment: Welcome. Without an expert in PulseView to offer help, we may not be able to help you. Strictly speaking, this is a software issue, not a electronic design issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to get answers to these questions, courtesy of the [sigrok-devel](https://sourceforge.net/p/sigrok/mailman/message/36622909/) mailing list:

> > - Why did PulseView decide to map byte value 0x00 to -500 mV, and byte value 0xFF to 500 mV? In other words, how did it decide on this default range - is this documented anywhere, and can I change the interpreted analog range (in volts)?
>
> The range of the data type you use (0..255 for u8) is mapped to the
>   voltage range of -0.5V and +0.5V, as you noticed. That is not done
>   within PulseView, it's a property of the input module `raw_analog`.
>
> See
>   https://sigrok.org/gitweb/?p=libsigrok.git;a=blob;f=src/input/raw_analog.c;hb=HEAD#l55

And for the second question:

> > - When I use Sample rate (Hz): 0, PulseView seemingly choses 10 ms as sample period by default. Why is this number chosen, and is this documented anywhere? (I expect if I enter a proper sampling rate, then I'll get the corresponding sampling period instead).
>
> That's not the behavior I see. For me, using a sample rate of 0
>   results in PV using samples as the measurement scale, as indicated by
>   the "sa" unit shown in the timeline. In this case, any protocol
>   decoder can't give proper timing information and actually shouldn't.
>   How did you come to the conclusion that 10 ms sample period is used?

I came to that conclusion, because when I tried the experiment described in OP, I captured it on [this image in OP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO5mf.png) ... and there I can see the timeline in ms; and I can count approx 10 samples between 0 and 100 ms, and thus I arrived at 10 ms sampling rate.

However, that experiment was done with `pulseview-0.4.1-64bit-static-release-installer.exe` - in the meantime, I overwrote that and installed a nightly, which apparently installed version `0.5.0-git-58cd5b5` - and indeed, when I try the same experiment in that version, then I have timeline in units of "sa" (samples):

[image: binfile-pulseview-0.5.0-git-58cd5b5]

So that solves this issue for me now - thanks a lot to `sigrok-devel` again!